# Bootstrap grid columns overlapping in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-6">
             <app-profile [conId]="conId"></app-profile>
         </div>
         <div class="col-lg-6">
             <app-sales [conId]="conId"></app-sales>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[image: image of the overlapping divs]

I have no idea why this is happening.

Could it possibly be because I'm wrapping Angular component tags in the Bootstrap rows and columns? I'm almost certain I've done something like this before and it worked.

I've attached a picture of what's happening and highlighted where it's over lapping.

Edit:

Seems to look good if I remove the component tags and add some background color. So it may actually have something to do with the components themselves?

```
<div class="row">
    <div style="background-color: red; height: 20px;" class="col-lg-6">    
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: yellow; height: 20px;" class="col-lg-6">
    </div>
</div>
```

[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyMzW.png)

Comment: could you provide a fiddle .?

Comment: Probably something inside `app-profile` and `app-sales` breaks the layout somehow. Can you add code/styling for these?

Comment: The profile and sales components are just some content wrapped in a container div. Neither of them have their own style sheets, just bootstrap.

Comment: I believe @Ludevik is suggesting it's the content thats breaking the container.  Broken / missing tag issue.

Comment: Yea, maybe its just something simple there, but we can't tell. When you remove them from the component and just add color background to your `.col-lg-6` divs, does it work as expected?

Comment: Just tried that and it does seem to work. So something inside the components themselves are actually affecting it.

Comment: I'm going to try an figure out what's going on, if I can't will post the code from the components.

Comment: For some reason adding a col-lg-12 class to each components container div fixed it.